# why is ICMP checksum shifted 16 bits

Tags: haskell, checksum, icmp

I'm struggling to understand why the ICMP checksum total (before being complemented) is the total + shifted right 16 bits total in [this line of code](https://github.com/thesealion/Learning-Haskell/blob/c1396a29b93db9166afe802d1aac49b209c2a859/ping.hs#L56):

```
checksum bs = let bs' = (if (BL.length bs) `mod` 2 == 0 then bs else BL.snoc bs 0)
                  ws = runGet listOfWord16 bs'
                  total = sum (map fromIntegral ws) :: Word32
              in complement (fromIntegral total + fromIntegral (total `shiftR` 16))
```

**RFC 792** has this to say about calculating the checksum:

> Checksum
>
> The checksum is the 16-bit ones's complement of the one's
>     complement sum of the ICMP message starting with the ICMP Type.
>     For computing the checksum , the checksum field should be zero.
>     If the total length is odd, the received data is padded with one
>     octet of zeros for computing the checksum.  This checksum may be
>     replaced in the future.

I understand why `bs'` is calculated, as required by *"If the total length is odd, the received data is padded with one octet of zeros for computing the checksum."*

I can also understand summing the total of the 16 bit words done in this line of the code `total = sum (map fromIntegral ws) :: Word32`

I just can't figure out why in this line of code:

```
complement (fromIntegral total + fromIntegral (total `shiftR` 16))
```

that `` + fromIntegral (total `shiftR` 16) `` should be included at all.

NOTE: I have verified with wireshark that the checksum is only correct if I complement the `` total + total `shiftR` 16 `` as done in the linked line of code. So I know it is correct, I just don't understand why.

Comment: Perhaps, though your explanation is much clearer (at least to me). Also, I spent a while googling trying to find this answer.. it seems obvious now in hind sight seeing the link, but perhaps someone else will search in the same manner as I did and this will be helpful?

Comment: That's OK, [closed duplicates are not deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/229359) so someone else will be able to find it just the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC 1071](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1071.html) describes in detail the checksum definition, including this important part:

> On a 2's complement machine, the 1's complement sum must be
>   computed by means of an "end around carry", i.e., any overflows
>   from the most significant bits are added into the least
>   significant bits.

In your code,

```
total = sum (map fromIntegral ws) :: Word32
```

is the 32-bit sum, i.e. its low 16 bits is the sum without carries, and the high 16 bits will contain the sum of the carries. By using the fact that `fromIntegral :: Word32 -> Word16` does truncation, we have

```
low = fromIntegral total :: Word16
high = fromIntegral $ total `shiftR` 16 :: Word16
```

and so we can calculate the "end around carry" as

```
eac = low + high
```

Comment: Answers in the linked question suggest you have to do this twice to make sure the high bits go to zero.